# Nested array of objects to filter through , set properties then return parents recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

So I have this list of nested objects that I'm supposed to show in a web interface,

The nesting can go up to 4 levels deep

I need to filter it based on an object property (let's say `owner_id`).

The filter should recursively return parents if a child is nested inside while checking if it's a target object: set a property `.filtered=true` to it, if it is a parent: let's say we set `parent=true` to it.

The display depends on those properties in order to expand or collapse **parents** and highlight **filtered** ones using a different color

*(Quick side note: everything has an id, and I have access to a flat version of the objects array without nesting)*

My objects structure:

```
let objs =
[
    {
        title: 'title.1',
        owner_id: 1
        child_cards: [
            {
                title: 'title.1.1',
                owner_id: 2
                child_cards: [
                    {
                        title: 'title.1.1.1',
                        owner_id: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'title.1.1.2',
                        owner_id: 2
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'title.1.2',
                owner_id: 2,
                child_cards: [
                    {
                        title: 'title.1.2.1',
                        owner_id: 1,
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'title.2',
        owner_id: 3
        child_cards: [
            {
                title: 'title.2.1',
                owner_id: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'title.3',
        owner_id: 1,
        child_cards: [
            {
                title: 'title.3.1',
                owner_id: 1
            },
            {
                title: 'title.3.2',
                owner_id: 1
            },
            {
                title: 'title.3.3',
                owner_id: 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Example calling it with owner_id=2:

```
[
    {
        title: 'title.1',
        owner_id: 1,
        parented: true,
        child_cards: [
            {
                title: 'title.1.1',
                owner_id: 2,
                parented: true,
                filtered: true,
                child_cards: [
                    {
                        title: 'title.1.1.2',
                        owner_id: 2,
                        filtered: true
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'title.1.2',
                owner_id: 2,
                filtered: true,
                child_cards: [
                    {
                        title: 'title.1.2.1',
                        owner_id: 1,
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'title.2',
        owner_id: 3,
        parented: true,
        child_cards: [
            {
                title: 'title.2.1',
                owner_id: 2,
                filtered: true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Somehow every solution I found on StackOverflow doesn't include my case where I need to set specific properties to children/parents or **the algorithm instantly ignores any other child if it only finds one occurrence.**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example of the result tree after calling it for example with owner_id: 2?

Comment: @PabloA.Revert I've updated the original structure and added an example in the post, thank you for the comment I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this function solves the problem:

```js
    const source =
    [
        {
            title: 'title.1',
            owner_id: 1,
            child_cards: [
                {
                    title: 'title.1.1',
                    owner_id: 2,
                    child_cards: [
                        {
                            title: 'title.1.1.1',
                            owner_id: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'title.1.1.2',
                            owner_id: 2
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'title.1.2',
                    owner_id: 2,
                    child_cards: [
                        {
                            title: 'title.1.2.1',
                            owner_id: 1,
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'title.2',
            owner_id: 3,
            child_cards: [
                {
                    title: 'title.2.1',
                    owner_id: 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'title.3',
            owner_id: 1,
            child_cards: [
                {
                    title: 'title.3.1',
                    owner_id: 1
                },
                {
                    title: 'title.3.2',
                    owner_id: 1
                },
                {
                    title: 'title.3.3',
                    owner_id: 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

    const treatNode = (node, name, value) => {

      const filtered = node[name] == value
      const children = node.child_cards ? node.child_cards.map(x => treatNode(x, name, value)) : [];
      const filtered_children = children.filter(x => x.filtered || x.parent);
      const parent = filtered_children.length > 0;
      
      let ret = {...node};
      delete ret.child_cards;
      if (filtered) ret = {...ret, filtered: true};
      if (parent) ret = {...ret, parent: true};
      if (filtered_children.length > 0)
        ret = {...ret, child_cards: filtered_children};
      
      return ret;
    }

    console.log(source.map(x => treatNode(x, "owner_id", 2)).filter(x => x.filtered || x.parent))
```

Please let me know if is it what you are looking for.

Comment: This is really good, but it lacks something, it went well in some test,
but not in an example where I have
filtered > parent > filtered

I really appreciate your work tho! this is really great 

Comment: in the snippet it's showing `{
    "title": "title.3",
    "owner_id": 1
  }` when it shouldn't

Comment: I  forgot to filter results, now I think it works ok. The only difference is the snippet does not show {title: 'title.1.2.1', ...} but I think this is the expected behavior

Comment: Ok actually thank you very much, this seems to be working, I had some confusion, I can't thank you enough :)!

Comment: You are welcome, please don't hesitate to ask, I will try to help you with what you don't understand. And please, if you consider this is the right answer accept it.